# How do I unlock Expert mode in DDR Supernova 2 for PS2?

Tags: dance-dance-revolution

I've been playing DDR Supernova 2 for the PS2 for months now.  I have gotten B's and A's on almost every song I have unlocked on Expert difficulty, but I still am not able to select Expert difficulty when first starting a session.  I hit a wall in in the Master Mode, and can't beat any more levels beyond around level J.

Will I be able to unlock Expert mode just by playing songs in the normal mode of playing, or do I have to beat things in Master Mode or Battle Mode?

Answer (score 2):

When you "Select Difficulty", "standard" makes all song choices available.  There is no "expert" option to unlock.

Comment: Interesting.  The other DDR games I've played have had three difficulty levels to choose from, but I guess they decided to have two in this one.  Thanks for your help.